# Trouble Modelling Objects with Curved and Straight parts

Tags: modeling

I've been struggling a lot modelling certain parts of a guitar that contain a combination of curves and straight paths.

When I did the body of the guitar I used a subdivision modifier and I got it looking perfect cause the body is all around smooth and curved. For the headstock I need a combination of straight edge and curves. Tried using the Bevel tool and also failed

https://imgur.com/a/aUlXMOx

Blender file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jzPy_X0y_TUTtg9tox4_TPZzuo2dH8Nx?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately it is not clear to me what exactly the issue is you are trying to fix. What is your question?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

For the headstock you can first follow the silhouette like this:

[image]

Then extrude:

[image]

Bevel this edges to keep them sharp:

[image]

Give a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, shade smooth:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, This has helped a lot. Still some issues though [This is my shape, looks very close to yours](https://imgur.com/a/T7T33tA) but when I add the subsurface I don't get the same results. [This is one with the subdivision modifier in "Catmull-Clark"](https://imgur.com/a/3RlyEb7) and this is [with the modifier on simple](https://imgur.com/a/RIurGYp). One looks too round, the other too sharp. Tried changing the size of the bevel but it hasn't helped

Comment: Use Catmull-Clark, not Simple, Simple won't give any roundness. If it's too round you need to add some support edge loops, if you are talking about the edges where you've beveled, make is less large and add a segment (2 segments instead of 1)?